# How to update a method on a Button click?

Tags: android

My code updates the calender only one time when `Button` is clicked .It doesn't update the Calender when the `Button` is clicked again.I want to update dates in weekly basis.Below is my code and logcat,

```
 public class myCalendar extends Activity {

public final static String[] monthcalender = { "January", "February",
        "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September",
        "October", "November", "December" };

public final static int daysinmonths[] = { 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31,
         30, 31, 30, 31 };

int mon, yr;
int j=0;
Calendar todaycldr;

// myCalendar moncldr = new myCalendar();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_calendar);

    Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);



 //      if (mon == 2) {
  //        displayMonth(Integer.parseInt(args[0]) - 1,
//       Integer.parseInt(args[1]));
 //      } else {
     todaycldr = Calendar.getInstance();
displayMonth(todaycldr.get(Calendar.MONTH), todaycldr.get(Calendar.YEAR));
    // }


    button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            j=7;
            displayMonth(todaycldr.get(Calendar.MONTH), 
    todaycldr.get(Calendar.YEAR));

        }
    });

}

private void displayMonth(int month, int year) {

    // The number of days to leave blank at
    // the start of this month.

    int blankdays = 0;
    System.out.println("  " + monthcalender[month] + " " + year);

    if (month < 0 || month > 11) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Month " + month
                + " is not valid and must lie in between 0 and 
    11");
    }

    GregorianCalendar cldr = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, 1);
    System.out
            .println("Sunday Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday  
 Saturday");

    // Compute how much to leave before before the first day of the month.
    // getDay() returns 0 for Sunday.

    blankdays = cldr.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - 1;
    int daysInMonth = daysinmonths[month];

    if (cldr.isLeapYear(cldr.get(Calendar.YEAR)) && month == 1) {

        ++daysInMonth;
    }

    // Blank out the labels before 1st day of the month
    for (int i = 0; i < blankdays; i++) {
        System.out.print("   ");
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= daysInMonth; i++) {

        // This "if" statement is simpler than messing with NumberFormat
        if (i <= 9) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.print(i+j);

        if ((blankdays + i) % 7 == 0) { // Wrap if EOL
            System.out.println();
        } else {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        if (i % 7 ==0)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_calendar, menu);
    return true;
}

   }
```

**Logcat**

```
    09-04 01:00:37.727: I/System.out(591):   September 2013
   : Sunday Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday
     1  2  3  4  5  6  7
         September 2013
 System.out(591): Sunday Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday
     System.out(591):  8  9  10  11  12  13  14
 I/System.out(591):   September 2013
 : I/System.out(591): Sunday Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday
 I/System.out(591):  8  9  10  11  12  13  14
 I/System.out(591):   September 2013
  I/System.out(591): Sunday Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday
 09-04 01:01:20.017: I/System.out(591):  8  9  10  11  12  13  14
```

Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Create a constructor and move this code in it:

```
public myCalendar() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        todaycldr = Calendar.getInstance();
            year = todaycldr.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    monthOfYear = todaycldr.get(Calendar.MONTH);


    }
```

and the call displayMonth in oncreate:

```
displayMonth(monthOfYear, year);
```